# Why does Joomla debug show 446 queries logged and 446 legacy queries logged?

Tags: joomla, performance, legacy, virtuemart

I have been called in to fix the performance of a Joomla site that was already setup.

I look at the debug output and it shows the same queries twice, once for queries logged and again for legacy queries logged. My guess is that it is actually running the same queries twice make for just under 900 queries per page (hope I am wrong)

The Legacy plugin is disabled, so Legacy mode is not on at all. The site uses VirtueMart as well (which BTW isn't working properly if the cache in the Global Config is turned on)

Besides the fact that I don't think it should be running 446 queries anyway (sometimes even up to 650 per page ), has anyone every experienced this issue, and where would I look to fix this.

Update:

Answer the question below... It is running Artio JoomSef, along with the System - SEF plugin

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer... I've been struggling with this for a long time. This is being caused by the Virtuemart Product Snapshot plugin. If you disable this plugin your legacy issues will go away.

I have contacted virtuemart about this.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same Problem. But I also have the problem with a fresh jommla / virtuemart installation. (I have tried local with xampp and sample products).

If I activate the legacy plugin, the numer of legacy queries is always 4.

ps: sorry for my bad english...

perhaps this link can help you to speed up the queries. (but I can't find the string in the shop_browse_queries.php)....

http://forum.virtuemart.net/index.php?topic=65103.0

Comment: thanks this helped find some performance issues, but still have the other issue going on. I am guessing it is just a bug, not sure yet